# Is there a way to filter on categories via dropdown using jquery FastLiveFilter?

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter, search, filter

I am using [THIS](http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/) FastLiveFilter -jquery plugin, to filter in my searchresultspage Inside my codeigniter project.

I'm wondering if the code from FastLivefilter can be edited so I can use a dropdown with categories. The plugin is made for an input field, but that's not what I want.

I populate my dropdown with the categories found when I searched. But I want to filter on a specific category so the list is getting shorter.

**My form (using the plugin) looks like this:**

```
<div class="zoekfilters">

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.search_input').fastLiveFilter('#search_list');
        });
    </script>

    <input type="search" class="search_input" placeholder="Type to filter">

    <br/><br/>

    <select class="search_input" id="selection">
        <option disabled selected>Choose a category</option>
        <?php foreach($all as $cat){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $cat['categorie']; ?>"><?php echo $cat['categorie']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

</div>
```

My dropdown is populated with 3 categories now.

- administrative
- sales
- communication

The plugin provides autocomplete too. so when I type the results are coming automatically.

I just want to have a dropdown select option, so I can filter on category.

Comment: can you provide the live url ??

Comment: It's a bit complicated, because of the sql search function. it still bugs a bit. http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/home/vacatures Type 9101 in the small input and click Zoeken Then you're at the results page, you click on 'extra zoekfilters' and 3 inputs are shown. But only one works at the time, I can't use them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go just call this script

```
$('#category_id').fastLiveFilter('#search_list');
<select id="category_id">
<option value="">select</option>
<option value="t">t</option>
<option value="S">S</option>
</select>
```

`#search_list` is the id of your container in which your records are
I have test it on the demos site of this plugin and it is working perfectly

**[See Fiddle i have created for you](http://jsfiddle.net/HJQsp/26/)**

Comment: I tried something like that already with search_input2 and search_input3. but the fields can't work together. it's either the input or the dropdown or the second dropdown. not all at the same time.

Comment: you have a bad structure of html in `ul` there is no `li` direct `fieldset` ??

Comment: I just used fieldset to add a border around it. but without or with `li` item it works. I added it but that's not the problem.

Comment: Could you help me with this?

Comment: How could i help you tell me i will try my best

Comment: I wonder if you know some jquery plugin or a method to filter with multiple searchfilters. I asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485283/how-can-i-filter-my-searchresults-with-multiple-filters-dropdown-keywords-etc would you look at it?