# How can I filter my searchresults with multiple filters? (dropdown, keywords etc)

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, filter

I have a Codeigniter website with a searchfunction. I am able to search on postal code and a keyword. Now I would like to have searchfilters on my 'searchresults' page to narrow the searchresults.

I am using [Fastlivefilter](http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/) jquery plugin now, but I would like to filter on multiple things.

- A dropdown with categories from my database
- Keywords that I type into the input field.

I got it working with ONLY the dropdown and ONLY the input, but not together.

Maybe there's a better way of doing it? Using [JQuery Filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for example?

My searchform:

http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/vacatures

How to use:

- type '9101' into the small input, that says 'postcode'.
- Submit the form and click on 'searchfilters' now try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example i have created for you hope it gives you the idea that you are trying to implement

Consider this html that contains the `ul li` structure  with two search fields

```
<ul>
    <li>bob bope</li>
   <li>bob test</li>
    <li>bob bones</li>
    <li>bob bobs</li>
    <li>test mcBridge</li>
</ul>
<br>
Search: <input id="search" class="search" length="24" />
Refine    <input id="refine" class="search" length="24" />
```

And here is the `jquery` which searches as well as refines the results considering the values of both text fields

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search").keyup(function(){
        $("li").hide();

        if($("#refine").val()!=""){
        var term = $("#search").val()+" "+$("#refine").val();
        }else{
        var term =$("#search").val();

        }
        $("li:contains('" + term + "')").show();

    }); 

});
```

**[Try my fiddle for lower case](http://jsfiddle.net/HJQsp/27/)**

[**Try my fiddle for upper case**](http://jsfiddle.net/HJQsp/28/)

I hope this what you were looking for , for testing write **bob** in first field  then write **test** in other field you will see only one result

Comment: One question. I need to search the exact word. so with Uppercase. I tried to add `var term = $("#search").val().toLowerCase()+...` but it did not work. How can I search on lowercase?

Comment: Try my fiddle it is working as per you need but i dont know how you have implemented in your project

Comment: Your fiddle works. But in my project I have list item from database that contain Uppercase words. How can I search when converting the uppercases to lowercases.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. when I search on bridge it shows 0 results. but when i search Bridge it finds 1. Refine doesn't work also. When you search for 'test' and then refine it with bob. 0 are shown.

Comment: Edit: Uppercases work. But the refine is a bit buggy. you can't refine to bob if you inserted test in the first searchbox

Comment: Edit2: uppercases only work if ALL the letters are uppercase. I need just the first one or none.

Comment: Man whats with it and i dont know what you want you want to search and then refine but i think your needs will never end till your complete project will be developed sorry enough from my side and now its your turn sorry if found my words as rude thanks

Comment: It's just that the Lowercases aren't working. the rest is working.